# CSS line-height renders differently on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

The following code renders as expected in Firefox and Chrome browsers, but on Safari it renders with an unwanted white line between the borders.

HTML:

```
<span>Text here</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  border-top: 3.3em solid #ff9933;
  border-right: 3.3em solid #ff9933;
  border-bottom: 3.3em solid #ff9933;
  border-left: 3.3em solid transparent;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Firefox and Chrome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helioalb/0kougrav/1/)

Comment: Looks like Safari just can't accept your zero line-height.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a problem of proportion, the border 3.3em can't cover totally the text with font-size 1em; you can change the border for 3.5em or you can change the font-size for 0.8em.

```css
span {
border-top: 3.3em solid #ff9933;
border-right: 3.3em solid #ff9933;
border-bottom: 3.3em solid #ff9933;
border-left: 3.3em solid transparent;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 0.8em;
line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>Text here</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Safari finds your line height (if zero line height can be called *height* :)) unsatisfactory for such a *small* border. Does work fine with `3.5em`.

```css
span {
border-top: 3.5em solid #ff9933;
border-right: 3.5em solid #ff9933;
border-bottom: 3.5em solid #ff9933;
border-left: 3.5em solid transparent;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>Text here</span>
```